# Python win32 PostMessage/SendMessage click on mouse position, not position given

Tags: python, automation, pywin32

I'm trying to make a python program to drive a video game in the background, so I can do something else at the same time on the same computer. For that I use the win32 library and it works very well with keyboard input and mouse clicks. The only problem is that when I do a mouse click, the mouse click is done where my mouse is currently pointing (on the game and not on my screen) and not on the indicated coordinates. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

```py
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Video Game")

coords = (10, 10)

coords = win32api.MAKELONG(coords[0], coords[1])

win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coords)
win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, coords)
win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, coords)

win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coords)
win32api.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, coords)
win32api.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, coords)
```

Here is the complete code that I currently have, I have tested all the methods that there is in comment, and all the ways to get the coordinates that I could find but none of them works. This program displays:

- handler : 7341658
- tmp1 : 655370
- tmp2 : -1572878
- tmp3 : 327690
- tmp4 : -25

```py
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import time


def LeftClick(handle, coords):

          coords1 = coords
          coords2 = win32gui.ScreenToClient(handle, coords)

          # Return 0, is invalid
          # handle1 = win32gui.ChildWindowFromPoint(handle,client_coords1)

          # It's the same handle
          #handle2 = win32gui.ChildWindowFromPoint(handle,client_coords2)

          tmp1 = win32api.MAKELONG(coords1[0], coords1[1])
          tmp2 = win32api.MAKELONG(coords2[0], coords2[1])

          # find on another stackoverflow response, not work
          tmp3 = coords1[0] << 15 | coords1[1]
          tmp4 = coords2[0] << 15 | coords2[1]

          # None of them work
          print(handle, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4)

          win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
          win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, tmp1)
          win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp1)
          win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp1)

          win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
          win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, tmp1)
          win32api.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp1)
          win32api.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
          time.sleep(2)

          coords = (10, 10)
          handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Video Game")

          # click but not at coords
          LeftClick(handle, coords)
```